# How do I check the currently loaded view controller ? (ObjC + Swift)

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, global-variables

In my app I have a function where I want it to print something depending on the current view controller that is loaded. I do this by setting a global variable (Bool) and then toggling the flags in the view controller classes. From my main class I have something like this:

```
var FirstViewControllerisVisible: Bool = false
var SecondViewControllerisVisible: Bool = false
var ThirdViewControllerisVisible: Bool = false

@objc func PlayAgainfunc(_ sender: Any) {
    if counter % 15 == 0 {
        if FirstViewControllerisVisible == true {
            print("First View Controller is visible")
        } else if SecondViewControllerisVisible == true {
            print("Second View Controller is visible")
        } else if ThirdViewControllerisVisible == true {
            print("Third View Controller is visible")
        }
    }
    counter += 1
}
```

Then, in those classes I can set the flags like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    FirstViewControllerisVisible = true
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    FirstViewControllerisVisible = false
}
```

This worked great when it was exclusively Swift, but the problem with global variables is that they can't be accessed by Objective-C. I can't find a way to set flags in my ObjC classes and then check if true or false. For instance, If I tried:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated; {
    [(FirstViewControllerisVisible) == true];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated; {
    [(FirstViewControllerisVisible) == false];
}
```

I would get the error 'use of undeclared identifier' because my global vars declared in Swift are Swift only.

Comment: _Swift Tips:_ Swift variables and function names are `lowerCamelCase`, so `firstViewControllerisVisible`  and `playAgainfunc`. Also, don't add `func` to the end of a function name… so just `playAgain`. And no need to include `the == true`, so `if firstViewControllerisVisible {` etc.

Comment: Also…  `[(FirstViewControllerisVisible) == true];` is all wrong. `==` is a comparison, not an assignment, and why surround in `[ ]`?

Comment: I need to put the == true because firstViewControllerisVisible is a global variable Boolean I made up. By default it’s false and when viewdidappear is triggered the flag gets set to true. Also, I guess the Objective-C is wrong, I’m not as well versed in that as Swift. I’m trying to do in Objective-C what I’ve been doing in Swift, but global variables declared in swift can’t be used by ObjC. That’s what I’m trying to figure out, how to set a flag in Objective-C to read if the VC is visible or not and then execute a function based on that in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

After the view controller has loaded, you can

```
if let viewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
    print(type(of: viewController))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add below mentioned extension. you will get the desired result.

```
extension UIApplication {
        /// will return currently showing view controller
        static var topMostViewController: UIViewController? {
            return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.visibleViewController
        }
    }

    extension UIViewController {
        /// The visible view controller from a given view controller
        var visibleViewController: UIViewController? {
            if let navigationController = self as? UINavigationController {
                return navigationController.topViewController?.visibleViewController
            } else if let tabBarController = self as? UITabBarController {
                return tabBarController.selectedViewController?.visibleViewController
            } else if let presentedViewController = presentedViewController {
                return presentedViewController.visibleViewController
            } else {
                return self
            }
        }
    }
```

and access it like:

```
let viewController = UIApplication.topMostViewController
```

**Happy Coding**